# How to find payments transaction via itunes ?

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes, app-store-connect, payment

How to find payments transaction via itunes ? is it possible?

I have iOS App based on subscription model. Sometimes users complain that they paid but didn't recevie purchased content. So, how can I verify it? How to find transcaction on serverside or into itunes connect. ??
All payment gateways have admin panel where I Can find transaction by email, date, amount, day,id.
I have user email. How to manage subscriptions ? Please help.

Comment: If they say they purchased it and it was successful then just ask them to "Restore Purchase". There is no way to verify with Apple, Apple handles all of it for you, another reason why they insist on developers having a restore purchase button in their applications.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you can see it under "Sales and Trends" (iTunes Connect), iAP are listed as iAP (inApp Purchases).
You can see which country and what kind of Device, also the Date it was sold.
There is no other Way to determine if somebody purchased than through iTunesConnect...

edit: you can then ask your user to tell you when he bought so you can guess if he is lying or not.

also, in code you can get a verification if the purchase was successful. you could then notify yourself with an HTTP request if you own a web server (with more Information)...

Comment: Is this still the case or is there a way to search now?